Econometrics Question - Causal effect in a non-randomized trial
I am trying to establish a specification of a binary choice model (logit/probit) that dictates treatment assignment. The context (and subsequent cross-sectional data) is related to a government that assigns subsidies to firms that claim that they will improve their investment into sustainable technology.
I seek to establish the ATET of firms that were awarded the subsidy. I am therefore using a propensity score matching method of estimation. Crucial to this is to create a matched sample of treated and non-treated firms, by predicting propensity scores (probabilities) that the firm was awarded the subsidy.
I have some time-invariant dummy observables (whether firm is based in a city, the industry, type of ownership), however another variable that I have is on employee count, which proxies for firm size. I however get entirely different estimations for ATET when I include employees (no. of employees that work here). Should I be estimating the $Pr(subsidy=1)$ conditional on employees or not?

The issue is that the subsidy may induce firms to hire more employees to carry out their sustainable investment programme, if awarded the subsidy. I do not know if this means that I should not include employee count as a control variable in generating pscores for the likelihood of subsidy award-ation/assignment.

Would anyone be able to advise on this?
Thank you.
